# How do I convert the CURL command to Guzzle HTTP

Tags: php, laravel, curl, postman, guzzle

I am wondering how do I turn this CURL to the Guzzle,

```
curl -XPOST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'x-client-id: 275432e3853bd165afbf5272' -H 'x-client-secret: 2279c0ffb9550ad0f9e0652741c8d06a49409517' -d '{
  "orderId": "Order0001",
  "orderAmount":1,
  "orderCurrency":"INR"
}' 'https://test.cashfree.com/api/v2/cftoken/order'
```

I tried importing this curl request as raw in POSTMAN and POSTMAN gave me php code which eventually on copy pasting to my controller worked.

**Working Controller Code**

```
public function cashfreeToken(Request $request)
{
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => "https://test.cashfree.com/api/v2/cftoken/order",
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>"{\n  \"orderId\": \"Order0001\",\n  \"orderAmount\":1,\n  \"orderCurrency\":\"INR\"\n}",
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Accept: application/json",
        "x-client-id: 275432e3853bd165afbf5272",
        "x-client-secret: 2279c0ffb9550ad0f9e0652741c8d06a49409517",
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);
    dd($response);
}
```

But I would like to know how to I convert the same request in Guzzle. I tried and I am getting 400 response errror

**Non Working Guzzle Controller Code**

```
**public function cashfreeToken(Request $request)
{
    // dd('working');
    $headers = [
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'x-client-id' => '275432e3853bd165afbf5272',
        'x-client-secret' => '2279c0ffb9550ad0f9e0652741c8d06a49409517'
    ];

    $GetOrder = [
            'orderId' => 'N10139',
            'orderAmount' => '123',
            'orderCurrency' => 'INR',
    ];

    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $request = $client->post('https://test.cashfree.com/api/v2/cftoken/order, ['headers' => $headers]);
    $request->setBody($GetOrder, 'application/json');

dd($request);
    // dd($response->getBody()->getContents());
}**
```

**Api.php**

```
Route::post('cashfreetoken', 'Api\CashFreeController@cashfreeToken');
```

**POSTMAN**

[image]

**Error Stack**

```
{"status":"ERROR","subCode":"400","message":"orderId is required"}
 in file /var/www/html/say-cure-web/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php on line 113

#0 /var/www/html/say-cure-web/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php(65): GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException::create(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response))
#1 /var/www/html/say-cure-web/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(203): GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response))
#2 /var/www/html/say-cure-web/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(156): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::callHandler(1, Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Array)
#3 /var/www/html/say-cure-web/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/TaskQueue.php(47): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::GuzzleHttp\Promise\{closure}()
#4 /var/www/html/say-cure-web/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(246): GuzzleHttp\Promise\TaskQueue->run(true)
#5 /var/www/html/say-cure-web/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(223): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->invokeWaitFn()
#6 /var/www/html/say-cure-web/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(267): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->waitIfPending()
#7 /var/www/html/say-cure-web/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(225): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->invokeWaitList()
#8 /var/www/html/say-cure-web/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(62): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->waitIfPending()
#9 /var/www/html/say-cure-web/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php(183): GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise->wait()
#10 /var/www/html/say-cure-web/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php(96): GuzzleHttp\Client->request('post', 'https://test.ca...', Array)
#11 /var/www/html/say-cure-web/app/Http/Controllers/Api/CashFreeController.php(30): GuzzleHttp\Client->__call('post', Array)
#12 [internal function]: App\Http\Controllers\Api\CashFreeController->cashfreeToken(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#13 /var/www/html/say-cure-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(54): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#14 /var/www/html/say-cure-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(45): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('cashfreeToken', Array)
#15 /var/www/html/say-cure-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(219): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(App\Http\Controllers\Api\CashFreeController), 'cashfreeToken')
#16 /var/www/html/say-cure-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(176): Illuminate\Routing\Route->runController()
#17 /var/www/html/say-cure-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(680): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run()
#18 /var/www/html/say-cure-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(130): Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#19 /var/www/html/say-cure-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(41): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#20 /var/www/html/say-cure-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#21 /var/www/html/say-cure-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(59): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#22 /var/www/html/say-cure-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure), 60, '1')
#23 /var/www/html/say-cure-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php(43): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#24 /var/www/html/say-cure-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure), 'api')
#25 /var/www/html/say-cure-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(105): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#26 /var/www/html/say-cure-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(682): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#27 /var/www/html/say-cure-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(657): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#28 /var/www/html/say-cure-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(623): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route))
#29 /var/www/html/say-cure-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(612): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#30 /var/www/html/say-cure-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(176): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#31 /var/www/html/say-cure-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(130): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#32 /var/www/html/say-cure-web/vendor/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/src/Middleware/InjectDebugbar.php(65): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#33 /var/www/html/say-cure-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Barryvdh\Debugbar\Middleware\InjectDebugbar->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#34 /var/www/html/say-cure-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#35 /var/www/html/say-cure-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#36 /var/www/html/say-cure-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#37 /var/www/html/say-cure-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#38 /var/www/html/say-cure-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#39 /var/www/html/say-cure-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#40 /var/www/html/say-cure-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(62): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#41 /var/www/html/say-cure-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#42 /var/www/html/say-cure-web/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#43 /var/www/html/say-cure-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#44 /var/www/html/say-cure-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(105): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#45 /var/www/html/say-cure-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#46 /var/www/html/say-cure-web/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#47 /var/www/html/say-cure-web/public/index.php(55): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
```

Response Code generated by POSTMAN

Any help on this would be much appreciated

> Using version ^6.5 for guzzlehttp/guzzle and Laravel Version 6

Comment: Remove the `\n` from your json. In fact, instead create an array with the values then use [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) instead so that it's a properly formatted json.

Comment: Your initial cURL CLI call contained `Content-Type: application/json`, then in your working controller code it becomes `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (although the data you are sending is still JSON) – is there any logic behind this, or are you just wildly guessing here?

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin They are all dummy. Those Creds Wont work

Comment: @04FS I actually tried adding  'Content-Type'=> 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', to headers and I am still getting the same error

Comment: Why are you adding _that_, when you are sending JSON? And your original cURL CLI command used something different in the first place?

Comment: Can you even call `setBody` after `$client->post`, does that make sense? I would assume that the `post` method fires the request immediately - so you would be setting the request body, _after_ the request was already send. (And that would explain why the receiver complains not getting its data.) Try and specify the body content directly in the `post` method call instead. (You‘ll have to take care of encoding your array as JSON yourself then.)

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin I think you meant that to go to the OP, not me.

Comment: Youre correct @anyber

Answer (score 3):

The error message indicates that the request to the API endpoint is missing the `orderId` parameter. This could be because the request body is not being sent correctly.  You're setting the request body using the setBody method in your Guzzle request. However, this method is not part of Guzzle's API. Instead, you should pass the request body as a JSON string in the json option of the post method.

```
public function cashfreeToken(Request $request)
{
    $headers = [
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'x-client-id' => '275432e3853bd165afbf5272',
        'x-client-secret' => '2279c0ffb9550ad0f9e0652741c8d06a49409517'
    ];

    $order = [
        'orderId' => 'Order0001',
        'orderAmount' => 1,
        'orderCurrency' => 'INR',
    ];

    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $response = $client->post('https://test.cashfree.com/api/v2/cftoken/order', [
        'headers' => $headers,
        'json' => $order
    ]);

    dd($response->getBody()->getContents());
}
```